# Will this make the block leak?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c-blocks

Will any of these codes cause the block to be permanentely allocated on memory? I mean, a reference inside the block to the strong spinner outside?

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
  [spinner startAnimating];
}];
```

or

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

[self.queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
  [spinner startAnimating];
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't. The spinner is owned by its super view. The variable spinner is presumably a local variable, so as soon as it goes out of scope, it stops retaining the spinner. Likewise the block runs once and then stops, so it won't retain the spinner once it finishes.

Comment: but supposing the spinner was allocated on that line it would leak, right?  ah, I was thinking the other way around... the spinner holding the block.